# Display label on a Tableau bar chart

Tags: tableau-api

I have this bar chart in Tableau. The third column is the percent difference between the first two columns. I do not want to display the third column. I want to display the value of the third column on the shelf of the second column. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use the 'percentage differece' table calculation on the text as shown below.

[image]